# Obj C - Creating Unique Property List Keys using 'For'

Tags: objective-c, property-list

```
for (int x = 0; x < openSlots; x++) {
    NSNumber* slotValueSave = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[slotValues objectAtIndex:x] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"Saving slot %@.", (x+1));
    [valueSavesDictionary setObject:slotValueSave forKey:@"Slot Value %i", (x+1)];
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to saving up to 9 string and corresponding numbers to a property list key. I don't want to write out every key @"Slot Value 1", @"Slot Value 2", etc.

So I was wondering how I could have the 'for' statement insert the 'x' integer after every title to be saved under that key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+stringWithFormat:`:

```
[valueSavesDictionary setObject:slotValueSave forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slot Value %i", (x+1)]];
```

Comment: Amazing. 5 minutes and I got an answer. I can not thank you enough Richard. Cheers man.